# Getting an array of dates between start date and end date

Tags: javascript, date, sharepoint-2013

I have a problem with a function I wrote in Javascript. I am trying to get an array of dates between start and end.

The function :

```
function getDateArray(startDate, endDate) {

    var dateArray = new Array(),
    currentDate = new Date(startDate),
    lastDay = new Date(endDate);
    while (currentDate <= lastDay) {
        if (!(currentDate.getUTCDay() === 0 || currentDate.getUTCDay() === 6)) {
            //currentDate.toUTCString(); //This line is redundant
            dateArray.push(currentDate);
        }
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return dateArray;
}
```

Whenever I call this function with two dates like :

Start Date = 10/6/2015
and End Date = 10/12/2015

I get the unwanted result :

```
Tue Oct 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
Tue Oct 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
Tue Oct 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
Tue Oct 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
Tue Oct 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
Tue Oct 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
Tue Oct 13 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)
```

Please if anyone can highlight to me what is wrong here?

Comment: `currentDate.toUTCString();` is a no-op; you have to assign the result somewhere. If the goal is to push the string form, you need to push the return of that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are pushing a reference to currentDate each time (as date are complex type, they are passed by reference)

Just replace this :

```
dateArray.push(currentDate);
```

By that :

```
dateArray.push(new Date(currentDate));
```